# Storing the context in shared preference

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

How can i store a context in shared preference ? Is it possible? if yes, then give some hint and if possible sample code..

Comment: why on earth would you need to do this?

Comment: Why do you wish to store the context object? Context is also in most cases a "ContextWrapper" delegating calls to other objects. Take a look at the class hierarchy at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Answer (score 2):

The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of **primitive** data types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: **booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings**.
You cannot save Context.